# Determine if $\forall xQx \rightarrow \exists yQy$ is valid

Tags: logic

I am learning how to draft proof of mathematical logic. Here is my work so far, but I don't feel comfortable, as it is unclean;

'=' is present in this language, and $Q$ is a 1-place predicate symbol:

Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be any structure, and $s:V \rightarrow |\mathfrak{U}|$ be any assignment function. We want to show that $\vDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \forall xQx \rightarrow \exists yQy[s]$, by the definition

$$\vDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \forall xQx \rightarrow \exists yQy[s]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\vDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \forall xQx [s] \longrightarrow \vDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \exists yQy[s]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\forall d_x \in |\mathfrak{U}|, <d_x>\in Q^\mathfrak{U} \longrightarrow \exists d_y , <d_y> \in Q^{\mathfrak{U}}, \text{by the definition of }s(x|d)$$

Suppose for the contradiction that $\nvDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \forall xQx \rightarrow \exists yQy[s]$, then it will only be the case that $\vDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \forall xQx[s]$, but $\nvDash_{\mathfrak{U}} \exists yQy[s]$.
Which is a contradiction already, as $\forall d_x \in |\mathfrak{U}|, <d_x>\in Q^\mathfrak{U}$, it cannot be that $\nexists d_y , <d_y> \in Q^{\mathfrak{U}}$

I feel so sick about my proof. It is awful. And that is the reason I post this, I want to learn the formality of proof.

Comment: I have to admit I have no idea whether this is true, but in the mathematicians every day logic it is not, since, for the empty set, $\forall x Qx$ is valid (for any $Q$), while the existence claim fails.

Comment: @Thomas Usually in first-order logic, the domain is assumed to be non-empty. This presupposition is encoded in the fact that you can always apply a universal elimination and existential introduction, which would indeed allow you to go from $\forall xQx$ to $Qa$ to $\exists y Qy$.

Comment: Basically, your proof is correct; the key point (as per comments above) is that the domain of the interpretation must be non-empty, otherwise the step $∃d_y \in |\mathfrak U| (d_y Q^{\mathfrak U})$ fails.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the comments, let us look into the case a bit further.

In the standard unsorted logical setting, the given sentence is equivalent to

$$\forall xPx\rightarrow\exists xPx$$

which provides a more perspicuous form for the underlying idea. Calvin Jongsma gives a clear explanation of its evaluation in his *[Introduction to Discrete Mathematics via Logic and Proof](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/introduction-to-discrete-mathematics-via-logic-and-proof)* (p. 116-17; the boldface is mine, the italics are in the original):

> $\forall xPx\rightarrow\exists xPx$ is logically true. To show this,
> we must argue that $∃xPx$ is true whenever $∀xPx$ is. If $∀xPx$ is
> true, then all members of universe $U$ have property $P$, however $P$
> is interpreted. Certainly, then, some member of $U$ has property $P$,
> i.e., $∃xPx$ is true. (This depends upon the fact, unstressed until
> now, that *only non-empty sets* are accepted—by **convention**—as
> *bona fide universes of discourse*.)

What is the basis of this convention? We may reason in two ways in case that a domain of discourse is empty (beware of the distinction between an empty domain and an empty extension of a predicate $P$):

- $\forall xPx$ is false $\implies\neg\forall xPx$ is true $\implies\exists x\neg Px$ is true

Since the domain is empty of objects one of which could be assigned to $x$, this is an incoherent interpretation, given the standard definition of $\exists$.

- $\forall xPx$ is true $\implies\neg\exists x\neg Px$ is true

Since a non-existence claim is made, this is a coherent interpretation.

Therefore, we can agree on evaluating $\forall xPx$ to true in case of an empty domain of discourse. Notice that this strips $\forall xPx\rightarrow\exists xPx$ off validity.

Though, an empty domain of discourse (i.e., kind of [nothingness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/)) is not an absurd idea and worth consideration philosophically, it is hardly a meaningful possibility for many branches of knowledge, including mathematics. So, it is convenient to regard empty domain of discourse as a logical singularity and disregard it standardly.

It should be remarked that there are various logical systems that aim at dealing with the issue of non-existence among other metalogical complications. But they are beyond the scope of the present question.